# How to display PDF link in Sitecore page

Tags: sxa, media-library, links, pdf

I'm using Sitecore 9 and SXA 1.7.

I have a few PDF files that I have uploaded into media library/files/myfolder, and an "instructions" template whose fields are title (type: single line text), Date (type: date), description (type: single line text), and file (type: file).

I have created a few items of type "instructions", and in each of their "file" fields there is one PDF file from the media library/files/myfolder path.

My question is: I created a search results component that searched for these "instructions" items, and I need it to *view a download link for these PDF files.* Specifically, to view a link that the user can click on, which opens the related PDF file in a new tab or so.

So far I've used the rendering variant to display each item's Name and Date, but I do not know how to show a download link for the PDF file. I have tried using reference->file in the rendering variant, but it shows nothing on the results page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you create variant items under reference field? You need to display something in order to render a link.

It works fine on my machine. Here are screenshots with the setup:

**Template**
[image]

**Content**
[image]

**Media Library** (`Title` field is not filled automatically)
[image]

**Variant** (pass through: `File`)
[image]

**Results in EE**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I was struggling with showing the link and didn't think of just writing something and linking the variant to the Title field! I also searched a bit and found out how to stop the force download when I click on the PDF link (by changing the forceDownload attribute in Sitecore.config for pdf extension to false), now it opens the file in the same tab .. is there a way to open it in another tab onclick, which is my requirement?

Comment: I found the answer : I just set the "link attributes" field in the rendering variant to "href" --> "_blank" and now when i click on the link it opens in a new tab .. thank you!